# Need package path for RemoteControlReceiver?

Tags: android, wear-os, intentfilter, receiver

I am trying to make an existing android app wearable.

Is it necessary, or not, to specify the full package path for setting a media button event receiver?

I haven't seen any explanation in the official documentation. It is as follows in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html):

```
<receiver android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

While I have this in my current code:

```
<receiver android:name="com.pckg.my.app.subpack.RemoteControlReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I edited your question to include an actual question. Still, you should edit your question, and explain what the problem is with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add (.) in the beginning of your android name

```
<receiver android:name=".com.pckg.my.app.subpack.RemoteControlReceiver">
```